# Bazel build failing on Apple Mac M1

Tags: java, bazel, apple-m1, jarjar, bazel-java

Facing below issue when running
bazel run //api/deployment:mynamespace.apply
Please let me know if anyone also faced same issue.

Bazel Version:- 4.2.1
Processor:- Apple Mac M1

ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_akashtyagi/e7d0288ce9b933c729b37bd014ecd495/external/bazel_tools/third_party/jarjar/BUILD:10:30: no such target '@remote_java_tools_darwin//:JarJar': target 'JarJar' not declared in package '' defined by /private/var/tmp/_bazel_akashtyagi/e7d0288ce9b933c729b37bd014ecd495/external/remote_java_tools_darwin/BUILD and referenced by '@bazel_tools//third_party/jarjar:jarjar_import'

Answer (score 1):

You should use @remote_java_tools_linux//:JarJar target. For more [reference](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/7767).